# Get single instance class label using Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I'm using LSTM-RNN with Tensorflow. I'm passing a complete dataset and only one instance as test. After classification process, I want to get only the label of the class of that probe. Right now I'm doing this for calculating accuracy:

```
one_hot_predictions, accuracy, final_loss = sess.run(
    [pred, accuracy, cost],
    feed_dict={
        x: X_test,
        y: one_hot(y_test)
    }
)

test_losses.append(final_loss)
test_accuracies.append(accuracy)
```

I'm also considering a y_test.txt file that contains the labels of the single instances in test dataset for calculating the accuracy, but in this case it is useless.
Please, help me, guys. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please provide an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is my example: I have some files with one case per line. These files are features. I created a pharser for them. The system is loading them as DATASET data. A side file called y_train contains the same line of them and for each line I have a class. So, the files are features and the lines are cases. Than, I have the same number of files files (features) that contains only one line (one case). These files are my TEST data. Now, I want to make my system return the most probable class of that case using LSTM with RNN over my DATASET. That's all. Thanks

Comment: Right now, the code I wrote, is good when I need to calculate accuracy with more cases in TEST and adding an y_test file like for the train dataset...